# Deploying with git

Tags: python, django, git, deployment, production

Currently I have a bunch of git repos for a django site i'm looking to deploy, the repos' take the form:

```
sn-static
sn-django
sn-templates
[etc]
```

I then have a *super* repos that stores each of these as a submodules. In terms of deployment, I want to try to keep things fairly simple, would it be a valid method to:

- Clone a stable tag from the super repos & therefore have stable clones of each repos in one place.
- As the names are sn-* I would then look the symlink to a more friendly structure e.g. `ln -s /path/to/super-repos/sn-static /home/site/media/`
- Then my nginx webserver (in the case of static content at least) could simply refer to /home/site/media

Without a great deal of technical knowledge i'm unsure if symlinking would have any implications, in terms of speed or stability. I'm also wondering if I can get away with this as a method of deployment, rather than, say, using something like Capistrano (that as yet I have no experience with).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option you should consider is using [`pip`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) in conjunction with [`virtualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to install your packages especially as pip has the option to [directly install certain branches or tags](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirement-format.html) from a git repository.
That way you can use one requirements file to handle all your dependencies, your own packages and apps by other people. (See [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20140316174138/http://bartek.im/blog/2010/07/13/django-environment.html) for the big picture.)

And to handle your static media I'd prefer to use Django's builtin [staticfiles app](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) instead of symlinking several dirs, as it seems cleaner and easier to manage.

Answer (score -1):

When you reach a release point in your code, tag it ([Git Tag](http://book.git-scm.com/3_git_tag.html)). On your server, clone the master branch once and then simply to pull the release tag you want, each time you do a release.

```
git pull [tag]
```